# Using localhost in app setup for development

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

This not a good day in IPP land. Spent the last 2 hours messing with an app that worked fine 5 minutes before that. I keep getting invalid token errors when I try to call the QB API.

I tried replacing the consumer key & secret with those from another app we have in development. Works great. The only difference I can see is that the working app has "localhost" set up as the Host Name Domain.

OK fine. Tried to change the domain to "localhost" on the failing app. No can do. You have to enter a valid domain name. Huh? Tried to change the app name on the app that works. Won't let me save the change because the domain name isn't valid.

It seems pretty clear that the Host Name Domain is the problem here, but why can't I use localhost in development, when I already have an existing app that does that.?

I should add that I'm currently using Intuit's sample web forms app as a wrapper for some code that I'm developing. It is that code that's throwing the exception, not mine. So the problem isn't in my code; it's got something to do with the way the app is set up @ Intuit.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having the exact same issue trying to test on localhost.

Answer (score 4):

Please use a dummy host domain in development (e.g., example.com).  This setting will not affect your development testing.  We are working to clarify this in the documentation.

Comment: So it has to be a dummy, non-existent domain name? Because it doesn't work with a real domain.

Comment: What is the exception and when is it thrown?  During the OAuth flow?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the dummy host name somewhere in your application? If not, then I'm not sure how it should affect the sample app settings. Can you verify if the app keys passed are correct in the web.config?